# App-Settings of Function App are getting swapped in between function and slot

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-azure, blue-green-deployment

I am trying to deploy a Azure Windows Function App using Terraform AzureRM 3.66, over GitLab-CI pipeline. I am not able to add the exact code, but I can share almost the same sample. When I deploy the app-setttings of main function are getting deployed to Slot and app-settings of slot is getting deployed on to main. Let me know if I am missing anything. Any correct reference will be very helpful on this.

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example" {
  name                 = "example-windows-function-app"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  service_plan_id      = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "dotnet"
    "SOME_APP_SETTING_KEY"    = "main-func-value"
    "ANOTHER_APP_SETTING_KEY" = "main-func-value"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_windows_function_app_slot" "example" {
  name                 = "example-slot"
  function_app_id      = azurerm_windows_function_app.example.id
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name

app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "dotnet"
    "SOME_APP_SETTING_KEY"    = "staging_value"
    "ANOTHER_APP_SETTING_KEY" = "staging_another_value"
  }
}
```

After this to swap slot below running on a separate slot-swap-job:
`az functionapp deployment slot swap  -g MyResourceGroup -n MyUniqueApp --slot staging --target-slot production`

But this is setting the main app settings on to slot and slot-app-settings on to main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `sticky_settings` to `azurerm_windows_function_app`

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example" {
  name                 = "example-windows-function-app"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  service_plan_id      = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "dotnet"
    "SOME_APP_SETTING_KEY"    = "main-func-value"
    "ANOTHER_APP_SETTING_KEY" = "main-func-value"
  }
sticky_settings = {
    app_setting_names = [ "SOME_APP_SETTING_KEY", "ANOTHER_APP_SETTING_KEY" ]
  }
}
```

It will mark these settings as slot settings and do not swap them during deployment.

You need this only in `azurerm_windows_function_app` resource.

Comment: Thanks @krzysztof-madej . One small change on above I would like to suggest is as below: 
`sticky_settings {
    app_setting_names = [ "SOME_APP_SETTING_KEY", "ANOTHER_APP_SETTING_KEY" ]
  }`

Comment: @MukteswarPatnaik could you consider upvote my reply if it was helpful?